# Is it possible to sort Search result current site wise?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

I am working with SharePoint Online site collection. Here I am having a requirement that I have multiple sub-sites and in every sub-site I am having common lists with same name with Items.

Now I want that if I search something on the sub-site's Search box then it should first display the item from the current site from which I am searching and then from other sites.

Is it possible to work with such requirement with default search?

**For Example :-**

If I am searching the text using search textbox from **`Site-A`**, then the search results from **`Site-A`** should be on the top and then all other results.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sorting, but you could create a "Promoted Result Block" Query Rule. This way there could appear a result block at the top of the search results containing results from the current site.

To create a new Query Rule, get started at site collection's root > Site Settings > Query Rules. Choose `Local SharePoint Results (System)` as your Result Source > Click "New Query Rule".

The query in your case could be e.g. `Path={Site.URL}` ("Path" "Equals" "This site") or `Path={Site.URL}*` ("Path" "Starts with" "This site").

Have a look at the O365 documentation about Query Rules: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-query-rules-53556bb4-3625-490b-aa89-1223e3d4ce3f

Comment: You could also try creating a query rule that promoted the local site content above the more distant content.